# Modelo Relacional de um Banco

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional

A dúvida é a seguinte, eu tenho a seguinte situação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No lado direito eu tenho o conhecimento matemático - MK e do outro lado o Conhec. Didático - PCK, vamos chamar eles de Domínio, e em cada um deles, dividido no meio do hexágono, eu tenho três outros tipos de conhecimentos, vamos chamar eles de Subdomínio. A situação que eu tenho que resolver é, para cada subdomínio eu tenho que adicionar situações, e cada situação tem várias questões com alternativas diferentes, segue um exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No caso a questão 2 diz respeito a mesma situação da imagem acima.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E as respostas, ou o feedback necessário segue nessa imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Todo esse desenvolvimento eu farei utilizando a framework Django, porém antes eu tenho que passar pela criação desse modelo relacional, enfim, isso foi o que montei até agora:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como não sou nenhum Expert em banco, gostaria da sugestão de vocês no que eu posso ajustar ou adicionar no modelo ou se tá tudo errado, enfim. Mas basicamente é, cada domínio pode ter até 3 subdomínios, ou mais e cada subdomínio pode ter apenas um domínio. Cada subdomínio pode ter várias situações, mas a situação só pode ter um subdomínio. Cada situação pode ter várias questões, ou seja, pra uma situação eu posso ter várias questões que vai uma apontando para a outra. E fora isso cada questão pode ter n alternativas. Essas questões devem ser respondidas por um participante, no caso um usuário do sistema. Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analisando a partir da descrição fornecida, o modelo em grande parte já está atendendo ao seus requisitos, creio que seu modelo ainda não esteja completo, porém ainda assim, eu gostaria de sinalizar algumas situações:

- Não existe (e não vejo a necessidade de existir) um relacionamento entre as tabelas
  **Participante** e **Situação**, pois em nenhuma delas existe um atributo que indique relacionamento entre elas.
- Verifique se há realmente a necessidade de existir dois 'IDs' na tabela **Participante**, já que ambos os atributos da tabela são inteiros, acho que você pode descartar um deles.
- Na tabela **ParticipanteResposta** você colocou mais chaves estrangeiras que o necessário, nesta tabela você só precisa guardar o ID do participante e o ID da alternativa escolhida por ele, pois, tendo o ID da alternativa você pode conseguir todas as outras informações que necessite de outras tabelas.
- As cardinalidades entre o relacionamento das tabelas **ParticipanteResposta** e **Alternativa** deveria ficar assim: **Alternativa** (1,1) ------ 
  (0,N) **ParticipanteResposta**, pois uma alternativa pode ou não ser escolhida como resposta pelo participante, e o participante só pode escolher como resposta uma única alternativa.
- A partir das imagens fornecidas, acho que deveria existir também uma tabela **Resoluçao**, pois vejo que cada questão tem minimamente resolução A, B, C e D, então seu relacionamento poderia ficar deste modo:
  **Resolução** (1,1) ------ (1, N) **Alternativa**.

Comment: Spock, muito obrigado pela ajuda, já fiz algumas alterações aqui e foi de grande valia. Porém não entendi muito bem o quarto ponto sobre a tabela Resolução, visto que o modo que você colocou pelo que vi já está assim: Questão (1,1) ------ (1, N) Alternativa

Comment: Já entendi, Spock. Realmente estava faltando essa tabela. Muito obrigado pela ajuda, amigo.

Comment: Que bom que você entendeu, não notei que fiz confusão com o nome das tabelas no último ponto, acabei de corrigir.